# cat alternative with syntax highlighting

Tags: cat, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a program like `cat` but with syntax highlighting. As an example I would like to display the content of one of my Python script highlighted in the terminal without using a pager like we do with `cat filename.py`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) is `cat` alternative with syntax highlighting and other functionalities. You can see some previews on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat). This is a fairly new program and may not be available in your favorite distribution repositories. In that case you will have to build it from source or to download the `.deb` package.

Comment: Excellent. I was using `pygments` but now will switch to `bat`. On Ubuntu 20.04 the package is called `bat` and the binary is `batcat`

Answer (score 2):

Try out generic coloriser: http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html (or better, the readme on https://github.com/garabik/grc). I looked at a few and this was one that "just worked". You can tweak the hilighting with your own regex, but I found it was really good straight out the box. You can pick whatever you want colorised, or use the automatic aliases provided for bash, zsh or fish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `source-highlight`. First, install the `source-highlight` package for your system, if available. On Debian-based systems, you can do this with `sudo apt install source-highlight`. On Arch, it's `sudo pacman -S source-highlight`.

You can now do:

```
source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i foo.sh
```

Which looks like:

[image: screenshot showing source-highlight output]
There are many options you can use to adapt the output to your preferences, see `man source-highlight`. And you can write a little wrapper function that makes it work as a `cat` alternative:

```
colorCat(){
    for f; do
     source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i "$f"
    done
}
```

If you add those lines to your shell's initialization file (e.g. `~/.bashrc` for bash), you can then do:

```
colorCat file1 file2 ... fileN
```

Personally, I find it more useful as an alternative to `less` and not `cat` since  source code files tend to be large and it's nice to have the ability to scroll back, search etc. To do that, you can use:

```
cless(){
    LESSOPEN='| source-highlight --failsafe --out-format=esc -o STDOUT -i %s 2>/dev/null ' LESS=-R less "$@" 
}
```

If you use this one with multiple files, you can move to the next file with `:n`.